# The process com.android.phone has stopped unexpectedly. Please try again

Tags: android, android-emulator

Whenever I run an Android emulator, I've got these errors such that it's impossible to work with it at all:

```
The process com.android.phone has stopped unexpectedly. Please try again.

The process com.android.acore has stopped unexpectedly. Please try again.
```

Or

```
 The application has stopped unexpectedly
```

The emulator's got all memory it needs (as far as I know):

[image]

**UPDATE**:
There is no log information in logcat.

[image]

Comment: What's the logcat say? Have you tried running the same app on a real device?

Comment: @codeMagic what's logcat, where do I find it? there is no application, I only want to run an emulator.

Comment: [Logcat](http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/ddms.html)  Window->Show View->Other->Android->Logcat   "Have you tried running the same app on a real device?"

Comment: @codeMagic, look at my update please

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I just ran across this myself.  Looks like you have to delete your virtual device and reload it.

http://www.redips.net/android/emulator-phone-stopped-unexpectedly/

Answer (score 6):

I had the sampe problem, this is the solution :

The solution:
Settings –> Applications –> Manage Applications –> All (button on the top that lets you see all applications) –> scroll down to “Contacts Storage” –> Click on “Clear Data”.

IT WORKED EVEN IN THE EMULATOR, you should do this to every emulator type you want to use, 
this is where I found the solutions : 
http://www.shaneycrawford.com/2011/12/how-to-fix-the-android-process-acore-problem-on-an-android-device/

Comment: perfect answer.. you save me :)

Answer (score 0):

Solving Unfortunately the process com.android.phone has stopped IN HTC>>>ANY MODEL

I was in this trouble for 6 days, 
I gave my cellphone to many Repairman And I asked them if any friend of them can fix it please do it.
But nobody with any expensive Boxes couldent to fix.
I got my HTC sensation and I was very sad.
But Abruptly I found a way. 
I did my cellphone to SUPER CID with ADB & FASTBOOT before.
Because of that change my phone didnt know my sim card.
Some peoples only get an update and they fall into this problem. I am in IRAN (middle east)
YOU MUST CHANGE YOUR CID TO YOUR AREA. 
in HTC Series CID s are here
http://forum.xda-developers.com/show....php?t=2445289
THIS IS ONLY WAY FOR PERSONS THAT ANY WIPE OR RESET DIDNT WORK FOR THEM.